# Replace space with '%20' in place in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to remove the spaces of a string in place by creating an array of characters that is bigger than the actual string and doing the replacement in place. However, it doesn't seem that the values are copied correctly.

I assumed that you could do `char a[7]="aaaa ";` so that you have more memory in order to do the replacement, but I guess I am wrong. The problem is that after running the code and printing `a`, I still get the same string `aaaa`

NOTE: Notice that I am trying to start writting from the end of the string, so overwritting is not a concern.

NOTE: The expected output for 'test space' would be 'test%20space'

```
int countSpace(char *str) {
        int nSpaces = 0;
        while (*(str) != '\0') {
                if (*(str) == ' ') {
                        nSpaces++;
                }
                str++;
        }
        return nSpaces;
}

int main()
{
  char a[7]="aaaa ";
  int alength = strlen(a);
  int newSize = alength + countSpace(a)*2;
  a[newSize] = '\0';
  newSize--;

  for (int i = alength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (a[i] == ' ') {
                  a[newSize] = '0';
                  a[newSize - 1] = '2';
                  a[newSize - 2] = '%';
                  newSize -= 3;
          } else {
                  a[newSize] = a[i];
                  newSize--;
          }
  }

  printf("%s", a);

}
```

Comment: what is the actual and expected output ?

Comment: And `a[newSize] = '0'; a[newSize] = '2'; a[newSize] = '%';` is just overwriting of characters.

Comment: brokenfoot, added a note with expected output. And no, I am not overwritting characters, because newSize is far away from the existing characters.

Comment: @StarTrek18 but `newSize` doesn't *change* between assignments. You put three successive characters in the *same place*.

Comment: @StarTrek18: Yes you are. `newSize` is an index and you are writing to the same index consecutively.

Comment: @StarTrek18 maybe you meant to write `a[newSize--] = '0'; a[newSize--] = '2'; a[newSize--] = '%';`

Comment: @StarTrek18, you've given the expected output, but not actual output or a description of where it presently fails.

Comment: I fixed that error. It was a typo, but the problem is still there. It seems the changes on the string don't take effect. @CharlesDuffy I added what is the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any satisfying way of doing this operation in place. I see that you're trying to do something clever by starting from the end; unfortunately, this doesn't really help.

Let's consider for a moment a small test case: the string `"abc def"`. No matter whether you start from the beginning or the end, you're going to run into that space when you're halfway through, and you're going to need to replace it with three characters (`%20`). To make this happen, you have to make the three characters beyond that space all scoot over two characters to make room, and that's annoying and difficult to do. (It's actually more difficult when you start from the end, as then you need to make the *beginning* of the string move backwards, which would require you to have space available before the beginning of the string. If you're going forwards, you can at least move the end of the string into space you've allocated beyond the end.)

Unless there's some reason that you absolutely need to do this operation in place, I'd strongly recommend that you use two buffers. It'll be far easier that way.

Comment: Ok, I understand. That's why I wanted to create a big enough buffer, so that I could start writing from the end. Somehow saying 'I know that my array have enough space at the end'. But I guess is not trivial in C. Thanks, this is what I needed to answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) for this:

You need to allocate memory long enough to support extra 2 chars for space. In the following snippet, `data2` is long enough to hold replaced spaces from `data`.

```
  // prepare memory long enough to hold %20 spaces
  char data[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  int newSize = strlen(data) + countSpace(data)*2;
  char data2[newSize+1];
  strcpy(data2,data);
```

Now let's replace in-place on `data2`:

```
  // replace the spaces in data2
  for(char*s=strchr(data2,' '); s!=NULL; s=strchr(s+1,' ')) {
    memmove(s+2,s,newSize+data2-s); // shift the rest of the string by 2
    memcpy(s,"%20",3); // replace ' ' for '%20'
  }
  data2[newSize] = 0; // end of string
```

Now the `data2` contains

> The%20quick%20brown%20fox%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong here:

```
 for (int i = alength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (a[i] == ' ') {
                  a[newSize] = '0';
                  a[newSize-1] = '2';
                  a[newSize-2] = '%';
                  newSize -= 3;
          } else {
                  a[newSize] = a[i];
                  newSize--;
          }
  }
```

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with the original code and how this fixes it. The correct code looks very much like the buggy one; it's hard to find the difference.

Comment: This doesn't work either, anyway; it'll destroy part of the string when it hits a space, and will write to unallocated memory when a space is present in the first two characters of the string.

Comment: actually .. firstly who posted the code missed -1 and -2 in line 4th and 5th of my code then he edited the code.. so seeing my post and his new updated code you are unable to find out any difference ...